# SwiftUI - How to set a non static var from a static function

Tags: swiftui

I'm currently following a [series of lectures from Stanford](https://cs193p.sites.stanford.edu/) to learn Swift (Code is from lectures 1-4 plus the homework I'm trying to complete) and am having an issue with setting an instance var(non-static) from a static function. I have gotten this to work but I would like it to be able to have different instances of the game have different themes

```
class EmojiMemoryGame: ObservableObject {
    
    //Create the model in the viewController
    @Published private var cardGame = EmojiMemoryGame.createMemoryGame()
    
    static let themesArray = [
        theme(name: "Halloween", color: Color.orange, emojiArray: ["","","","","","",""])
            {6},
        theme(name: "Aqua", color: Color.blue, emojiArray: ["‍☠️","","","⚓️","","","⛵️","","",""]) {Int.random(in: 5...7)},
        theme(name: "Animals", color: Color.gray, emojiArray: ["","","","","","","",""])
            {Int.random(in: 3...4)}
    ]
    
    static var selectedTheme: theme?
    
    //Public Static Function
    //Input: None
    //Output: MemoryGame<String> struct
    //Usage: Return the card game with emoijs inited
    static func createMemoryGame() -> MemoryGame<String> {
        
        //ISSUE
        //Want to get a random theme from the themes array and assign it to an instance of this class but get an error beceause the function is static
        selectedTheme = themesArray[Int.random(in: 0..<themesArray.count)]
        let emojisArray = selectedTheme!.emojiArray
        
        //Create the actual MemoryGame
        return MemoryGame<String>(numberOfPairsOfCards: selectedTheme!.numberOfCards(), cardContentFactory: { cardPairIndex in
            emojisArray[cardPairIndex]
        })
    }
    
    //Struct Theme
    struct theme {
        let name: String
        let color: Color
        let emojiArray: [String]
        let numberOfCards: () -> Int
    }
```

I want to be able to get a random `theme` from `themesArray` but let `selectedTheme` be an instance var. Can anyone give me some advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to declare your selectedTheme as static.

You just need to add an initialiser and change what is returned from the function that creates your memory game. I've removed some of the code to make it easier to see what I have changed.

Notice that we have removed the setting of `cardGame` to the `init`. We have also removed all reference to `selectedTheme` from `createMemoryGame`. The `createMemoryGame` function now returns a [tuple](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-a-tuple), which means that we can easily access the game and theme that it has created.

```
class EmojiMemoryGame: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published private var cardGame: MemoryGame<String>

    var selectedTheme: Theme // structs and classes should have capital letters
    
    /// This now returns a tuple of the game we have created and the theme that we have chosen
    static func createMemoryGame() -> (MemoryGame<String>, Theme) {
        
        let theme = EmojiMemoryGame.themesArray[Int.random(in: 0..<themesArray.count)]
        let emojisArray = theme!.emojiArray 
        let game =  MemoryGame<String>(numberOfPairsOfCards: theme!.numberOfCards(), cardContentFactory: { cardPairIndex in
            emojisArray[cardPairIndex]
        })
        return (game, theme)
    }

    // We add an initialiser to our class so that all the values that we need are initialised
    init() {
        let (game, theme) = EmojiMemoryGame.createMemoryGame() // note that the use of the names game and theme are arbitrary. 
        self.cardGame = game
        self.selectedTheme = theme
    }
}
```

Comment: This still returns the error `Instance member 'selectedTheme' cannot be used on type 'EmojiMemoryGame'` (the error I've been getting all along just with different vars and such). It almost seems like there is no way to use non-static vars in a static function and vice versa...

Comment: Sorry there was a typo. You should make sure that `selectedTheme` isn’t in the static method and that the local variable `theme` Is used in its place

Answer (score 0):

Just let your ThemesArray be a static variable like it is. However, you won't need to declare `selectedTheme` as `static`. As you say, it is an instance variable.

Declare `selectedTheme` as following:

```
var selectedTheme: theme?
```

Then initialize it like the following:

```
selectedTheme = EmojiMemoryGame.themesArray[Int.random(in: 0..<EmojiMemoryGame.themesArray.count)]
let emojisArray = selectedTheme!.emojiArray
```

Comment: I tried this at first but it gives me the error `Instance member 'selectedTheme' cannot be used on type 'EmojiMem` and `Instance member 'selectedTheme' cannot be used on type 'EmojiMemoryGame'`